# How to diagnose error loading task items lists?

Tags: permissions, alfresco

Current Alfresco version is 5.0a.

A user is unable to see any of his tasks (either Active or Completed). Sometimes a red bar appears with the text `Error loading items`, sometimes it just displays `Loading...`.  It works fine for everyone else. So far I don't see anything in the logs specific to that failure. We have changed some of his permissions in the past.

Anyone experienced this before and found a cause?

Is it possible he had a task that he no longer has permission to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that he was an administrator, with pending admin tasks when those privileges were removed.  That seems to be what broke his lists.  I cleaned them out by connecting with the Android app (which as admin shows everybody's stuff), and then his lists were back to normal.  Presumably, kicking him up to admin again, having him clean the lists, then dropping back down would have worked as well.